# How to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}$ converges uniformly?

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I know that
$$
\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)} \leq \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}},
$$
but I run out of my way to prove that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}} 
$$ converges. Please help.

Comment: Check that $\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n}} }$ it is a $p$-series: $$\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p}}}$$ with $p=\frac{3}{2}>1$ and therefore it is convergent. Also, since $n\geq 0$ we have:
$$\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}=\frac{x}{n+n^{2}x^2}\leq \frac{x}{n^{2}x^{2}}=\frac{1}{xn^{2}}$$
this impies by **Weierstrass M-test** that the series $ \displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x}{n(1+nx^2)}}$ is uniformly convergent when $x\geq 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was thinking to derive a closed form for the some. Anyway, the p-series statement is good enough though.

Comment: Your welcome :) !